# PHP splitt array with value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, split

i have an array with names as key and with countrys as value.
Now i want to know, which is the best, fastest and less code solution, to put the names of a country in one seperate array for each country.

My array:

```
Array
(
    [Smith] => USA
    [Laury] => USA
    [Chuck] => USA
    [Marc] => England
    [Lisa] => Germany
    [James] => England
    [Chayenne] => USA
    [Kurt] => Germany
    [Piet] => Netherlands
    [Klaus] => Germany
    [Antje] => Netherlands
)
```

and this is what i want:

```
Array USA ("Smith", "Laury", "Chuck", "Chayenne")
Array England ("Marc", "James")
Array Germany ("Lisa", "Kurt", "Klaus")
Array Netherland ("Piet", "Antje")
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Most Welcome. But, Where is your code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a foreach loop inserting in a new table the country values as key and name values as the elements.

```
$data = array(
    'Smith'=>'USA',
    'Laury'=>'USA',
    'Chuck'=>'USA',
    'Marc'=>'England',
    'Lisa'=>'Germany',
    'James'=>'England',
);
$temp = array();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $temp[$value][] = $key;
}
var_dump($temp);
```

Result:

```
array (size=3)
  'USA' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'Smith' (length=5)
      1 => string 'Laury' (length=5)
      2 => string 'Chuck' (length=5)
  'England' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Marc' (length=4)
      1 => string 'James' (length=5)
  'Germany' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Lisa' (length=4)
```